# Question on why the suggested Sentry LOGGING setting works

Tags: python, django, sentry, django-logging, python-logging

In the [Sentry documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/#integration-with-logging), the following setup for `LOGGING` is suggested:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s  %(asctime)s  %(module)s '
                      '%(process)d  %(thread)d  %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR', # To capture more than ERROR, change to WARNING, INFO, etc.
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
            'tags': {'custom-tag': 'x'},
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

All three of the loggers choose the `console` for their handler. Why would Sentry ever handle any logs? Is this because all three loggers inherit from the `root` logger, so setting `console` as the handler *adds* console to the existing sentry logger? Or something else?

Then, the comment on the `sentry` handler states "To capture more than ERROR, change to WARNING, INFO, etc.". Why would changing this to `INFO` handle `INFO` level errors? The `root` logger has set `WARNING` as its lowest level, and so how would any handler send an `INFO` level error to the `sentry` handler?

For instance, if I'm inside a file like `accounts/models.py`, and I call

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.info('test')
```

This should create a logger named `accounts.models`, which should inherit from the `root` logger. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#loggers) say that:

> When a message is given to the logger, the log level of the message is compared to the log level of the logger. If the log level of the message meets or exceeds the log level of the logger itself, the message will undergo further processing. If it doesn’t, the message will be ignored.

Why would `LOGGER.info('test')` send anything to Sentry in this case, if `LOGGER` inherits from the `root` logger which ignores everything at a level below `WARNING`?

Comment: I think this question does not fit the format of stackoverflow, as it's a post containing multiple questions at once. I suggest splitting up the question into multiple.

Comment: BTW this mess with logging configs is something we wanted to avoid entirely with the new SDK: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python